# Access container props in mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following interfaces:

```
interface EditUserContainerProps
  extends RouteComponentProps<EditUserParams>,
  EditUserStateProps,
  EditUserDispatchProps { }

interface EditUserParams {
  id: number;
  history: any;
}

interface EditUserStateProps {
  isLoading: boolean;
  isSubmitting: boolean;
  userFields: UserField[];
  User: User;
}

interface EditUserDispatchProps {
  load: (id: number) => void;
  updateUser: (User: User) => any;
  parseFile: (file: File, replace: boolean) => any;
  addRecords: (records: any[]) => any;
}
```

And I have the following `mapDispatchToProps` function:

```
export class EditUserContainer extends React.Component<EditUserContainerProps> {
....
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<ActionTypes>, ownProps: EditUserContainerProps): EditUserDispatchProps {
  return {
    parseFile: (file: File, replace: boolean) => {
      return fileParsingsApiActions
        .parseFile(file)(dispatch)
        .then((data: any) => {
           ownProps.addRecords( data.data);
        })
    }
  };
}

export const EditUser = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EditUserContainer);
```

In the callback for `parseFile`, `ownProps` is the props passed *into* my container.  I need access to the props *of* the container which include `addRecords`.

How can I get access to container props in `mapDispatchToProps`?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, you have access to ownProps where you are using it. What are the props of the container, isn't that just ownProps?

Comment: Can you show what the component hierarchy looks like? i.e. the main `render` functions?

Comment: @Dakota As stated, `ownProps` are only props passed into my container (in my case, none).  I want props that my container has created and mapped.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use mergeProps for this type of an interaction. It has access to all of the props for your container. Your addRecords is in your dispatchProps I believe so you can access it from there.

```
const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => {
  const props = Object.assign({}, ownProps, stateProps, dispatchProps)
  props.parseFile = (file: File, replace: boolean) => {
      return fileParsingsApiActions
        .parseFile(file)(dispatch)
        .then((data: any) => {
           dispatchProps.addRecords( data.data);
        })
   }

   return props;
}
```

From the documentation:
`[mergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps): props]` (Function): If specified, it is passed the result of `mapStateToProps()`, `mapDispatchToProps()`, and the parent props. The plain object you return from it will be passed as props to the wrapped component. You may specify this function to select a slice of the state based on props, or to bind action creators to a particular variable from props. If you omit it, `Object.assign({}, ownProps, stateProps, dispatchProps)` is used by default.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into this. I had looked into it before and it honestly seemed a bit confusing how to use.  Seemed like you had to define `mapStateToProps` and/or `mapDispatchToProps` and then `mergeProps` combined the two in who knows what way.

Comment: Nah you just get three objects, the state props, the dispatch props, and your props. Just do this assignment in there and you should be fine. You will have to build your entire props object in the function though.

Comment: So where do I define my `parseFile` dispatch action?

Comment: Just put it in mergeProps as a new property. So do the `Object.assign({}, ownProps, stateProps, dispatchProps)` and then just add a field to your props the same way you are in your return in mapDispatchToProps.

Comment: I added an example in my answer